# Заполнение формы на основе имеющихся данных

Tags: php, html, form

Допустим, есть форма:

```
 <form action="">
    <input type="text" name="in1" placeholder="">
    <select name="sex" id="sex-selector">
        <option value="0">Всех подряд</option>
        <option value="1">Девушку</option>
        <option value="2">Парня</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

Пользователь отправляет форму, получает результаты поиска. Но на верху эта же форма остается (как фильтр). Так вот, с помощью PHP я могу сделать, чтобы в поле `in1` стояло значение, которое отправил пользователь изначально:

```
 <form action="">
    <input type="text" name="in1" placeholder="" value="$GET['user-input']">
    <select name="sex" id="sex-selector">
        <option value="0">Всех подряд</option>
        <option value="1">Девушку</option>
        <option value="2">Парня</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

Но как быть с селектом? Ведь нужно писать `<option selected value="1">Девушку</option>`, а не в теле селекта указывать, какой option по умолчанию ставить..
Можно дикий костыль вроде:

```
switch ($this->selectedSex) {
    case '0':
        echo "
            <select name='sex'>
                <option selected value='0'>Всех подряд</option>
                <option value='1'>Девушку</option>
                <option value='2'>Парня</option>
            </select>
        ";
        break;
    case '1':
        echo "
            <select name='sex'>
                <option value='0'>Всех подряд</option>
                <option selected value='1'>Девушку</option>
                <option value='2'>Парня</option>
            </select>
        ";
        break;
    case '2':
        echo "
            <select name='sex'>
                <option value='0'>Всех подряд</option>
                <option value='1'>Девушку</option>
                <option selected value='2'>Парня</option>
            </select>
        ";
        break;
}
```

Но это же просто ужасно. Как быть в такой ситуации?
p.s. прошу не обращать внимание на синтаксис, а проникнуться сутью проблемы :)

Comment: У вас через ajax или с перезагрузкой страницы происходит поиск?

Comment: Нет, есть форма на главной странице, потом с нее переход на другую страницу, а там эта же форма. Ну да, т.е. с перезагрузкой

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое - использовать куки. Когда пользователь отправляет форму, записываем его выбор в куки и дальше уже с помощью js (это вариант, если у вас не реализован ajax - что скорее всего так) смотрим куки и на их основе заполняем быстренько форму.

На странице подключить `jquery` библиотеку и `ваш js файл`. Библиотеку скачиваем, а файл создаём.

```
<head>
  <script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/test.js"></script>
</head>
```

Когда отправляют форму, на стороне php начинают сессию и записываем в куки полученный выбор пользователя. Например, запишем пол (`sex`), который был выбран. Вместо значений `sex` и `2` можно конечно же использовать переменные php. Важно только, чтобы нигде внутри не было пробелов

```
<?php 
  //session_start();
  setcookie('sex', '2', time()+3600, '/'); //сохраняем куки на один час
?>
```

Страница пользователя перезагружается. Ему отображаются результаты поиска, а вверху та же форма поиска. Заполняем её значениями из кук с помощью jQuery (наш файл `test.js`)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    //После загрузки страницы получаем значение куки c именем sex
    sex=getCookie("sex");

    //устанавливаем значение выпадающего списка c id sex-selector
    if (sex) { //если в переменной не пусто
        jQuery("#sex-selector").val(sex);
    }

    //Функция получения значения нужной куки
    function getCookie(cname) {
        name = cname + "=";
        ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
});//конец ожидания DOM
```

Более красиво было бы всё сделать, конечно, без перезагрузки страницы и т.п. с помощью ajax, но и так хорошо.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="">
    <input type="text" name="in1" placeholder="" value="<?=$GET['in1']?>">
    <select name="sex" id="sex-selector">
        <option<?=$GET['sex']==0?" selected":""?> value="0">Всех подряд</option>
        <option<?=$GET['sex']==1?" selected":""?> value="1">Девушку</option>
        <option<?=$GET['sex']==2?" selected":""?> value="2">Парня</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Приведу тот способ, которым пользуюсь я - может вам он понравится

```
<?php $sex=['Всех подряд','Девушку','Парня']; ?>
```

```html
<form action="">
    <input type="text" name="in1" placeholder="">
    <select name="sex" id="sex-selector">
```

```
<?php for($i=0,$size=sizeof($sex);$i<$size;$i++):?>
    <option 
            value="<?=$i?>"
            <?php if($i==$_POST['sex']) echo 'selected';?>
            >
             <?=$sex[$i]?>
     </option>
<?php endfor;?>
```

```html
 
     </select>
    <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

Обычно мои ответы минусуют и возможно это будет мой последний ответ.

Поскольку пишу backend - то часто пользуюсь ajax, поскольку в моих приложениях поисковым роботам лучше не быть.
P.S. минусуют и даже не объясняют...

Comment: это упрощенный пример - как правило вместо $_POST я ставлю уже проверенные от пользователя данные, что бы не словить инъекции в базу данных